# Should we set some preferred standards for usage of romanization?

Tags: discussion

Romanization is an unavoidable reality of Korean-learning communities. But most learners will probably agree that it's a good practice to discourage becoming *dependant* on romanized Korean if at all possible.

What should our strategy be on this, if at all?

Answer (score 9):

I think we should avoid it whenever possible, I'm already seeing a lot of romanization in titles and posts. Maybe some resources for learning 한글 could be provided if we see a post with excessive romanization?

Comment: I'm a big fan of "avoid it whenever possible" but I also think that within the restrictions of StackExchange, it may be kind of difficult to encourage exclusive usage of Hangul. Hopefully we can find a reasonable compromise

Comment: Double commenting because I'm terrible. Perhaps we could add known-good resources in a tag-wiki for [tag:hangul]?

Comment: Maybe the correct friendly response would be to 'Hangulize' (is that the right word?) the text in question?

Comment: @topomorto I agree, however if the user is too low a level, they might not be able to understand the new question. In this case, they should put the 한글[han-geul] and then the romanization so that the asker can still understand the body&response

Answer (score -2):

Romanization is not used only for elementary language learners. It is absolutely required, as well as the standard, when it comes to discussing linguistic issues. Preferring one form of another depends on the type of question.

Also, it is important to recognize that hangeul is a 15th century script, which corresponds to Middle Korean. Prior to this is Old Korean, which is written in Chinese script. Old Korean includes sounds that no longer existed when hanguel was created, so it is simply not possible to write all Korean in hanguel.